# Distribut and align two views in LinearLayout (TextView + CheckBox) android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout

I may have not the right keywords to looking for an already existing answer. I am not English native so I do not really know how to exactly describe my issue. Please orient me to an answer or correct keywords and close and/or edit my question if needed.

**I want the checkbox to be align, no matter the size of the text next to it.**

Here is what I have so far using nested LinearLayout:

[image]

As you can see, when the price grow, the checkbox is not aligned anymore.

Here is the XLM file:

```
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        >


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itDelete"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_blue"
                android:scaleX=".9"
                android:scaleY=".9"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itName"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="TextView super mega trop long de la mort"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itMinus"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_remove_circle_blue"
                android:scaleY=".8"
                android:scaleX=".8"
                />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itAmount"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:text="10"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="22sp"
                />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/itPlus"
                android:layout_width="35dp"
                android:layout_height="35dp"
                android:layout_gravity="end|center_vertical"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_circle_blue"
                android:scaleY=".8"
                android:scaleX=".8"
                />


        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="2"
            >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/itTotalPrice"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:paddingEnd="5dp"
                android:paddingStart="5dp"
                android:text="20.00$CAD"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textStyle="normal"
                android:textAlignment="textEnd"
                />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/checkBox"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/in_the_cart"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:buttonTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                />
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Maybe I miss some arguments I do not know about.

Comment: Change the `<TextView>`'s and `<CheckBox>`'s `layout_width`s to `0dp`, instead of `wrap_content`.

Comment: Thanks! If you put it as an answer and maybe one or more explanation, I can mark you as the right answer